# Probability that a random vector has an acute angle with at least one vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, convex-geometry

I´m interested in the following problem:

Given a set of vectors $G = \{v_0, \ldots, v_n\}$, what is the probability $P$ that for any vector $u$, there is at least one vector $v_k \in G$ such that there is an acute angle between $u$ and $v_k$ (i.e. $u \cdot v_k > 0$)?

Notes: The vector $u$ has $d$ coordinates with $n \ll d$. Each coordinate of vector $u$ is sampled from a uniform distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ independently.

I'd appreciate it if someone could give me a pointer, and I'd be happy to just prove a loose upper bound on the probability (obviously tighter than $P > 0.5$) as well.

Comment: You cannot tell without knowing the probability distribution on $u$. For example, is $u$ independent of $G$? Is $u$ symmetric around $0$?

Comment: What is the distribution of the random vector $u$? The answer depends on this choice.

Comment: This probably goes without saying, but it also depends on $G$.  Though the fact that the elements of $G$ are unit vectors isn't actually relevant...

Comment: hi @acephalous, The vector u is independent of G and is randomly chosen from the unit hypersphere of dimension d.

Comment: @XanderHenderson you are right. I changed the question correspondingly.

Comment: Are you using the common terminology for angles as always non-negative, so acute angles are those between $0$ and $\pi/2$? Or are you including those between $-\pi/2$ and $0$?

Comment: @acephalous updated the question. should answer your question.

Comment: This feels a lot like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.  What are you *actually* trying to do?  What is this set $G$, and why do you care if a vector $u$ forms an acute angle with some element of $G$?  Without more information, the answer could be anything from $1/2$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability depends on $G$, and you cannot improve the bounds $0.5 \leq p \leq 1$ unless further assumption is made on the set. Indeed, taking $G$ to be any single vector $\{v_0\}$ implies $p = 0.5$, while taking $G$ to be $\{v_0, -v_0\}$ for any $v_0$ implies $p=1$.

For the two-dimensional case $d=2$, I'm pretty sure (but still need to prove that) the probability can explicitly be given as
$$ p = \min\left\{1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\max_i \{\theta(v_0, v_i)\}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\min_i \{\theta(v_0, v_i)\}\right\}$$
where $\theta(v_0,v_i) \in (-\pi, \pi]$ is the angle between $v_0$ and each other vector $v_i \in G$. I will try to add a proof shortly. The $d$-dimensional case seems less obvious, I need to think about it.

Comment: what kind of assumption on G would help to improve the bound? Any ideas?

Comment: I agree with you. I came up with a similar formula for the d=2 case but I am having a hard time proving it or extending it to higher dimensions.

Comment: "I will try to add a proof shortly" was curious if you have made some progress?

Comment: @Snared Completely forgot about this, apologies. Busy with work atm but would it help you significantly if I provided a proof when I find a moment in the next month or so?

Comment: @smalldog I mean yeah in the next month would be nice, no pressure from me though!

Comment: @Snared Not sure if I'll find the time but if I do, will keep you posted!