# Union of rectangular sphere subsets

Tags: uniform-distribution, spherical-coordinates, spheres

This question arises as a possible step in answering [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4117569/probability-that-a-random-vector-has-an-acute-angle-with-at-least-one-vector/4117656) unsolved question on MSE.

Assume a random vector $v$ is sampled uniformly from the unit sphere in $d$ dimensions, $v \in S^{d-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Assume we are given a finite collection of 'open rectangular' subsets $V_i \subset S^{d-1}$ in the sense of being written as
$$ V_i = (x_i^1, y_i^1)\times \cdots \times (x_i^{d-1}, y_i^{d-1}) $$
for spherical coordinates $x_i^1 < y_i^1 \in (-\pi, \pi]$ and $x_i^j < y_i^j \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ for $j\geq 2$. Assume we are given these $(x_i^j, y_i^j)$ explicitly. Then it is not so difficult to find an explicit formula for $P(v \in V_i)$ for any fixed $i$. I am looking for a way to compute
$$P(v \in \cup_i V_i)$$
when the sets $V_i$ are not disjoint (otherwise one could simply sum the probabilities of individual membership). This could either be an exact formula or an algorithmic procedure. I am running into the issue that the union of rectangular regions is no longer rectangular, so the probability is no longer easy to compute. Consider for example $d=3$ and
\begin{align}
V_1 = (-\pi, \pi) \times (0, \pi/2) \\
V_2 = (0, \pi) \times (-\pi/2, \pi/2) \\
\end{align}
i.e. $V_1$ is the upper hemisphere and $V_2$ the 'right' hemisphere. Then
$$P(v \in V_1) = P(v \in V_2) = 1/2$$
and in this case we can figure out that the union can be rewritten as a disjoint union
$$V_1 \cup V_2 = \left((-\pi, 0) \times (0, \pi/2)\right) \cup \left((0, \pi) \times (-\pi/2, \pi/2)\right)$$
to obtain
$$P(v\in V_1 \cup V_2) = P(v \in (-\pi, 0) \times (0, \pi/2)) + P(v \in  (0, \pi) \times (-\pi/2, \pi/2)) = 1/4 + 1/2 = 3/4 \,,$$
but I'm unsure how to do this in general. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please add some context. Where does the question originate from? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MSE Thanks for the tip, I have just added context.